# How to check given store isempty in ExtJS3

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I have store('mystore') i want to check given store is empty or not
please help to me I'm very new to ExtJs. I read ExtJsAPI but i can't find solution

```
if(isempty(mystore)){
    do something....
}
```

Comment: check http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-getCount

Answer (score 2):

```
if(mystore.getCount()==0) {
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `getTotalCount` method of store.

```
if(store.getTotalCount()>0){
     //Store is not empty
} else{
     //Store empty
}
```

or use `Ext.isEmpty` method.

```
if(!Ext.isEmpty(store)){
     //Store is not empty
} else{
     //Store empty
}
```